# Python - Add residuals to subplots generated by a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, subplot

I just can't get the subplots to work when adding the residuals with `add_axes`. It works well without residuals and I can add residuals to just one plot. This is an example of what I'm doing:

First, just to give you an idea of what I'm ploting, (t, y) is the data I want to plot, fit is the fit to the data, and diff is the difference between fit and data.

```
t, s, fit = [], [], []
diff = []
for i in range(12):
    t.append(x / y[i])

    s.append(np.linspace(0, 1, num=100, endpoint=True))
    fit.append(UnivariateSpline(t[i], y, er, s=5e20))
    diff.append(fit[i](t[i]) - y)
```

And this is the figure:

```
fig = plt.figure()
for i in range(12):
    plt.subplot(4,3,i+1)
    fig.add_axes((0.,0.3,0.7,0.9))
    plt.plot(s[i], fit[i](s[i]), 'r-') # this is the fit
    plt.errorbar(t[i], y, er, fmt='.k',ms=6) # this is the data 
    plt.axis([0,1, 190, 360])

    fig.add_axes((0.,0.,0.7,0.3))       
    plot(t[i],diff[i],'or') # this are the residuals
    plt.axis([0,1, 190, 360])
```

So as you can see I'm generating 12 subplots, which works just fine until I add the `fig.add_axes` to separate each subplot between data+fit and the residuals, but what I get is one messy plot on top of the subplots (figure has been shrunken to see the subplots under):

[image: messy plot]

And what I want is 12 subplots where each one looks like this:

[image: correct plot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually `plt.subplot(..)` and  `fig.add_axes(..)` are complementary. This means that both commands create an axes inside the figure.

Their usage however would be a bit different. To create 12 subplots with `subplot` you would do

```
for i in range(12):
    plt.subplot(4,3,i+1)
    plt.plot(x[i],y[i])
```

To create 12 subplots with `add_axes` you would need to do something like this

```
for i in range(12):
    ax = fig.add_axes([.1+(i%3)*0.8/3, 0.7-(i//3)*0.8/4, 0.2,.18])
    ax.plot(x[i],y[i])
```

where the positions of the axes need to be passed to `add_axes`.

Both work fine. But combining them is not straight forward, as the subplots are positionned according to a grid, while using `add_axes` you would need to already know the grid positions.

So I would suggest starting from scratch. A reasonable and clean approach to create subplots is to use `plt.subplots()`.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=3)
for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
    ax.plot(x[i],y[i])
```

Each subplot can be divided into 2 by using an axes divider ([`make_axes_locatable`](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html))

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
ax2 = divider.append_axes("bottom", size=size, pad=pad)
ax.figure.add_axes(ax2)
```

So looping over the axes and doing the above for every axes allows to get the desired grid.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
plt.rcParams["font.size"] = 8

x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi)
amp = lambda x, phase: np.sin(x-phase)
p = lambda x, m, n: m+x**(n)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=4, figsize=(8,6), sharey=True, sharex=True)

def createplot(ax, x, m, n, size="20%", pad=0):
    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
    ax2 = divider.append_axes("bottom", size=size, pad=pad)
    ax.figure.add_axes(ax2)
    ax.plot(x, amp(x, p(x,m,n)))
    ax2.plot(x, p(x,m,n), color="crimson")
    ax.set_xticks([])

for i in range(axes.shape[0]):
    for j in range(axes.shape[1]):
        phase = i*np.pi/2
        createplot(axes[i,j], x, i*np.pi/2, j/2.,size="36%")

plt.tight_layout()        
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the poor explanation, I have edited my question to make it clearer. I mixed the two approaches trying to plot in the same subplot both my data+fit and the residuals

Comment: Oh man, this is really completely different from the initial question. ;-)  I will look into it later.

Comment: This is awesome! It took me a while to implement it but now it's working great. Just one more thing, I can control the axes limits of the bottom part of the plot with `pyplot.axis` but I haven't managed to make it work for the upper part. Any advice for dealing with the axes limits?

Comment: When working with several axes like here, it is better not to use pyplot (as you will have problems to know which the current axes is, your working on.). Better directly work on the axes: `ax.set_xlim(0,4)` `ax2.set_xlim(5,10)`. same for `ylim`. Or `ax.axis([0,4,0,1])`, `ax2.axis([0,4,0,1])`.